# Double-stick magnets for wall / ceiling mount

Tags: mounting

I'm looking for magnets that will double-stick to the wall or ceiling, and will also double-stick to the item that I'm attaching to the surface. The idea here is that I'd like to attach USB-powered LED lights and USB battery packs to the wall or ceiling in a non-permanent manner in an apartment closet and kitchen.

Is there a better way of doing this, or a recommended magnet? I seem to be having trouble finding simple, double-stick magnets that have "both sides" of the magnet.

Comment: *All* magnets are 'double-stick'. There's no such thing (outside of theoretical physics perhaps) as a one-sided magnet (magnetic mono-pole ...?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your objective clearly, you wish to attach a magnet to one surface using adhesive tape. You wish to attach a magnet to another surface using adhesive tape. You wish to have the magnets attract to secure those two surfaces.

I have used double-sided foam tape, cut to the shape of a rare-earth magnet, attached after cleaning the magnet surface with alcohol. The same double-sided foam tape and magnet assembly was then attached to, for example, a television remote control.

It is important to match poles when you create these pairs. In my example, the solo magnet was stuck to the headboard of a bed, to enable a consistent location for the remote control.

In your description you prefer to have non-permanent attachment. This can be accomplished with a specific product or its equivalent. The specific product is known as 3M Command adhesive. It is also double-sided adhesive, with a tab extending from the assembly. One can purchase these strips in refill form. When you wish to remove them, the item is held securely, while pulling the release tab. Doing so deforms the foam and the adhesive, releasing the bond from the wall or surface.

The double-sided adhesive I use is weatherproof, but can be removed by carefully slicing it with a sharp implement such as a razor blade or sharp knife and the residue removed with common adhesive removal liquid.

With respect to the magnets, select your favorite vendor (eBay, Amazon, etc) and use "rare earth magnet" or "neodymium magnet" and look through the options. Flat, bar, sphere, disc shapes abound of various thicknesses and dimensions.

Comment: Thanks so much, it looks like the rare earth magnets are exactly what I'm looking for! Much appreciated.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan rare earth magnets may be **way** stronger than you want, though.  So strong they can be hazardous,    McMaster-Carr sells a variety of sheet  magnets of various more sensible strengths.

Comment: @Harper Thanks for that -- any recommendations on alternative magnet types? I downloaded the McMaster-Carr Android app, but they've got a huge selection.

Comment: I use the web browser UI and the search engine therein.  The app is just a gigantic awkward PDF of their catalog, which makes sense to engineering managers who have been using the yellow book for 20 years of their career, but as a newbie I find it hostile.

Comment: The strength of rare earth magnets are proportional to their size. I have 1 mm x 10 mm disc magnets that are quite strong when attached to each other. When placed on an item, there's just enough strength to keep them from sliding down the face of the refrigerator. Buying a 12 mm x 50 mm disc magnet may be overkill, however.

Answer (score 1):

The standard "roll of self-adhesive magnetic strip" (or classic printed refrigerator magnet) is neither "North" nor "South"; it's both, [alternating across the surface of the strip](http://www.physicscentral.com/experiment/physicsathome/zipmagnets.cfm). This is because a thin, wide flat magnet that has one pole across each surface won't actually be very strong, as you'll only get attraction at the edges where the magnetic field curls around to the other side. Having periodic Norths and Souths, though, makes for lots of transitions where you can get attraction between the magnet and a ferrous surface.

You can test this by taking two refrigerator magnets and trying to get them to adhere to each other. Rotate and slide them until you get the best adhesion; you'll then find that the two magnets easily slide along one axis, but you'll have a "zipper" effect when you slide them along the other, as the North and South poles alternately align and oppose each other.

This means that you can't reliably use two of these magnets to attach two objects together; sometimes you'll get good adhesion, and other times you'll actually get repulsion.

Comment: That's very interesting information, thanks. While I upvoted your answer for its useful details, the other posted answer has the key to what I'm looking for: "rare earth" or "neodymium" magnets.

Comment: No apology necessary; I agree it isn't the best answer. I just wanted to get the (relevant) info out there.